# Implementing operator< on abstract base class

Tags: c++

I have a type hierarchy, and I'm not sure of a clean / good way to implement `operator<` and `operator==`.

Essentially, I already have this:

```
class Parent {
    public:
        virtual ~Parent() {}
};

class A : public Parent { int         data; };
class B : public Parent { double      data; };
class C : public Parent { std::string data; };

bool operator==(A const & lhs, A const & rhs) { return lhs.data == rhs.data; }
bool operator< (A const & lhs, A const & rhs) { return lhs.data <  rhs.data; }

bool operator==(B const & lhs, B const & rhs) { return lhs.data == rhs.data; }
bool operator< (B const & lhs, B const & rhs) { return lhs.data <  rhs.data; }

bool operator==(C const & lhs, C const & rhs) { return lhs.data == rhs.data; }
bool operator< (C const & lhs, C const & rhs) { return lhs.data <  rhs.data; }
```

What I'd like to implement as well, is this:

```
bool operator==(Parent const & lhs, Parent const & rhs) { ... }
bool operator< (Parent const & lhs, Parent const & rhs) { ... }
```

I've currently implemented it by doing:

```
bool operator==(Parent const & lhs, Parent const & rhs) {
    try {
        return dynamic_cast<A const &>(lhs) == dynamic_cast<A const &>(rhs);
    } catch(std::bad_cast const & e) {
    }

    try {
        return dynamic_cast<B const &>(lhs) == dynamic_cast<B const &>(rhs);
    } catch(std::bad_cast const & e) {
    }

    try {
        return dynamic_cast<C const &>(lhs) == dynamic_cast<C const &>(rhs);
    } catch(std::bad_cast const & e) {
    }

    assert(typeid(lhs) != typeid(rhs));
    return false;
}
```

But this just seems awful. Is there a cleaner way of going about this?

Comment: `Parent` isn't an abstract class. Should it be? I'd also argue that your current approach is ugly on purpose. It is hard to think of a situation where something like that makes sense.

Comment: @pmr: I'd like `Parent` to be a key in a `std::map`. That's the reason behind this. I'm open for other methods of going about this that are less ugly, but nothing has come to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For comparisons of complex types, you may find [Double Dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) useful.

If your types are very simple, it is sometimes effective to roll them all into one. In the example of 3 unsigned variants, it would likely be better to just use one type to accommodate all sizes, and to avoid dynamic dispatch and more complicated graphs of types.

---

**Applied to original question; where A, B, and C all used unsigned types:**

well, one quick and dirty approach would be:

```
class Parent {
protected:
  virtual ~Parent() {}
public:
  bool operator<(const Parent& pOther) const {
    return this->as_uint64() < pOther.as_uint64();
  }
  // ...
private:
  // using a type which accommodates all values
  virtual uint64_t as_uint64() const = 0;
};
```

and then deriving from `Parent` would take the form:

```
class A : public Parent {
// ...
private:
    virtual uint64_t as_uint64() const { return this->data; }
private:
    uint16_t data;
};
```

then `Parent` could simply define all comparators, and all `Parent` types would be comparable.

Comment: The classes `A`, `B`, and `C` are more complicated then what I've presented them as. I could probably construct some `std::string` that I could do something like this with. But I was thinking there could be some other method to make this happen.

Comment: hmm - that detail should have probably been in the OP. anyways -- depending on the complexity of the type, you may need to resort to double dispatch: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch -- but that's cleaner than your solution in the OP.

Comment: Sorry about leaving out that detail. Tried to simplify the question to what seemed like the most important parts.

Comment: For now, I think I can do the uint64_t stuff for the classes I'm currently dealing with. The classes are going to get worse later, so I'll look into double dispatch at that point. Thanks!

Comment: @sharth ok - will update the answer to include double dispatch article

Answer (score 0):

Use a virtual comparator for single dispatch and `dynamic_cast` for type casting:

```
class ABC_base {
public:
    virtual ~ABC_base() {} 
    bool operator < (ABC_base const & rhs) const {
        return this->comparator(rhs) < 0;
    }
protected:
    virtual int comparator (ABC_base const &) = 0;
};

class ABC : public ABC_base {
protected:
    virtual int comparator(ABC_base const & rhs) const {
        try {
            return my_comparator(dynamic_cast<ABC const&>(rhs));
         // Run-time cast failed - use double dispatch as fallback
         } catch (std::bad_cast&) {
             return -rhs.comparator(*this);
         }
     }
private:
    int my_comparator(ABC const & rhs) const {
        if (data < rhs.data)
            return -1;
        if (data == rhs.data)
            return 0;
        if (data > rhs.data)
            return 1;
    }
    T data;
};
```

***Here's how the code works***:

The base class's `operator <` is called, which uses dynamic lookup to find the `comparator`. It checks the returned value to see if it's lesser.

The derived class's comparator attempts to downcast the base class reference so that comparison can be done on the derived class's members.

**Why the base class reference, instead of using the derived class reference?**
Virtual dispatch would not work otherwise due to incorrect function signature.

Should the downcast succeed, it calls the non-virtual private comparator. Otherwise, it uses virtual dispatch again to do `(rhs ? *this)` and negates the result to compensate for the inverted ordering.

**Why not have the cast and comparison in the one virtual function?** It will make the code messier since the function will do two things: casting *and* comparing. Hence, there's a private comparator function. Should you want to use the base function in a derived class, along the lines of `class ABC_der : public ABC`, call `ABC::comparator(static_cast<ABC const&>(rhs))`. The use of `Base::` forces *static* dispatch so you don't have to expose the helper comparison function.

Right now, `this` and `rhs` are of the same type, so we can *finally* do the actual comparison. A chain of `if` statements is used to return a value conformant to Java's `Comparable` and C's `qsort()` semantics.

Comment: @sharth: I've rewritten it to make it significantly simpler, and added a few paragraphs of explanation.

Comment: Doesn't allow a heterogeneous associative container with key `shared_ptr<ABC_base>` or similar.

Comment: @aschepler for heterogeneous comparisons via visitor pattern or double dispatch, the class will need to implement separate operators - truly heterogeneous comparisons are not going to work since you're doing general `T1,T2` comparisons. Other than hashing, there's no *general* form for this.